# managed property for created by field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I need to expose 'Created Date' and  'Created By' field of a particular list item in search results. Able to get the date field by mapping Basic:15(Date and Time) from this forum (http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40027/what-field-contains-the-created-date-in-a-sharepoint-search-index) but couldn't find which field represents 'Created By' field in the managed properties.

Is there any reference guide where we can find which managed property is mapped to which field?

TIA.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue some time back. I found that Office:4(Text) crawled property can be used for CreatedBy managed property and it gives correct results. I have blogged about it here:
http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.in/2012/02/search-using-createdby-metadata.html

[image]

Comment: we are on SharePoint 2010 and there is no property with name Office:4(Text). so, i tried including Office:office#Author(Text), but that did not work either.

Comment: I am also on SharePoint 2010 and can see this crawled property. Can you try following: New Managed Property --> Add Mapping --> Select Office in Category and then move between the pages until you find Office:4(Text)

Comment: When i do that, i am getting only these fields for selection. Office:office#Author(Text), Office:office#Editor(Text), Office:office#Owner(Text), nothing else that starts with Office.

Comment: @svs, please mark the question as answered.

Comment: Now, the issue is with identifying 'ModifiedBy' field. Which managed property represents 'ModifiedBy'? I tried all those which directly indidcates it as modified by ows_ModifiedBy(Text), ows_Modified_x0020_By(Text), ows_Last_x0020_Modified(Text), LAST-MODIFIED(Text) none of them are returning modifiedy by for me.

Answer (score 0):

ows_Created_x0020_By(Text)

and Created Date seems to be:

ows_Created_x0020_Date(Text)

Comment: Tried them, that did not work. only Basic:15(Date and Time) works for Created Date. For Created by, tried ows_Created_x0020_By(Text), ows_Created(Text), Office:office#Author(Text) etc., none of them are working

Comment: Yeah, zero documents that have ows_Created_x0020_Date so definitely not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh134087(v=office.14).aspx

Created By should be: ows_Created_x0020_By(Text)
Created Date isn't included in the index and needs to be assigned a managed property. You can easily create a new managed property called "ows_Created_x0020_Date" and assign it to the crawled property.

Comment: After creating new managed property for Created Date, to which crawled property I should map it to?