# Createdby managed property

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, search, web-services, managed-property

I need to get the **Created By field** of a document library item.
I am using the **search web services of SP2010**, but I do not know which managed property use to get that kind of information.

I tried

```
<Property name="CreatedBy"/>
```

but it is always null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreatedBy` managed property is mapped to `ows_Created_x0020_By(Text)`  crawled propery whereas `Author`  managed property is mapped to `Office:4(Text)` crawled property. If you add `Office:4(Text)` to `CreatedBy` managed property it should work. See here for more information:
http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2012/02/search-using-createdby-metadata.html

Comment: Is not crawled by default? That means I have to run a full crawl again :/

Comment: Most probably you need to do a full crawl again. I don't remember though, but you can test.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the Search Service Application and see if such a property exists.

If not create a new Property with Name = "CreatedBy" and add Crawled Property "Office:4(Text)" based on this post

[managed property for created by field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57087/managed-property-for-created-by-field)

Then do a full Crawl.